# Dutch National Flag - Not working for larger array

Tags: java, algorithm, dutch-national-flag-problem

My below Dutch National Flag solution doesn't seem to work for the given input array containing only 3 elements - 0, 1 and 2.

If I reduced the size of array, it works. I'm not able to identify the error.

Am I missing something ?

```
class DNF{

    public static void sort(int [] arr, int size, int low, int high) {

        if(size == 0)
            return;

        int lower = 0;
        int upper = size - 1;

        while(lower < size && arr[lower] == low)
            lower++;

        while(upper >=0 && arr[upper] == high)
            upper--;

        int temp = 0;
        int pivot;
        for(pivot = lower; pivot <= upper; ) {
            if(arr[pivot] == low) {
                temp = arr[pivot];
                arr[pivot] = arr[lower];
                arr[lower] = temp;
                pivot++;
                lower++;
            } else if(arr[pivot] == high) {
                temp = arr[pivot];
                arr[pivot] = arr[upper];
                arr[upper] = temp;
                pivot++;
                upper--;
            } else {
                pivot++;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int arr [] = {0,1,2,1,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,1};

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); //0 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 
        }

        sort(arr, arr.length, 0, 2);
        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); // 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE : Above same code works for smaller size array : http://ideone.com/bgEgCs

Comment: note: you can uses Arrays.toString(arr) to print your arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that the pivot must not be incremented when `arr[pivot] == high`.

And yes, I cheated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

Answer (score 1):

When you are arr[pivot] == high you should not move your pivot point the value you are switching with may not be the low value you are looking to switch with. You only know that the upper is now in the correct position

```
} else if (inArray[pivot] == high) {
    temp = inArray[pivot];
    inArray[pivot] = inArray[upper];
    inArray[upper] = temp;
    pivot++; //This line is not needed
    upper--;
```